# How to create a function that fills created list by a condition

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, so some of its logic is not clear to me.
I have trouble creating a function that generates a list with values determined by the following conditions:

- if the next value in a list is lower than a current one, it assigns 0
- in other cases -1

Data is:
`x = [1,2,3,3,2,1]`

This is a solution that satisfies condition:

```
y = [None]*(len(x)-1)
for i in range(0, len(y)):
     if x[i] > x[i+1]:
          y[i] = 0
     else:
          y[i] = 1
```

and so `y = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]`.

My problem is scaling this up: I want to make a function that processes N input lists (and outputs N lists) - script is below - I get the following:

```
def my_function(a):
     ynew = [None]*(len(a)-1)
     for i in range(0, len(ynew)):
          if a[i] > a[i+1]:
               ynew[i] = 1
          else:
               ynew[i] = 0
          return ynew
```

calling `z = my_function(x)`, z is equal to `[0, None, None, None, None]`.
How to solve this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Put your first snippet of code in a function, then call it for each input list.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the list inside the loop, so you only allow one iteration to complete. To fix, return at the end of the loop.

```
def my_function(a):
    ynew = [None]*(len(a)-1)
    for i in range(0, len(ynew)):
        if a[i] > a[i+1]:
            ynew[i] = 1
        else:
            ynew[i] = 0
    return ynew
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an indentation problem on the return, it must be taken out of the loop. In addition, to meet your conditions, you must reverse 0 and 1 in ynew.

```
def my_function(a):
    ynew = [None]*(len(a)-1)
    for i in range(0, len(ynew)):
        if a[i] > a[i+1]:
            ynew[i] = 0
        else:
            ynew[i] = 1
    return ynew
```